# Scrolling dynamic page till the end using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I`m trying to scroll the page till the end. My code works for several scrolls, but then an error occured: move target out of bounds

```
try:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://yandex.kz/maps/")
    time.sleep(3)
    input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]/input[1]")
    time.sleep(2)
    input.send_keys("Актау бар")
    time.sleep(2)
    input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)

    while True:

        scrollbar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "scroll__scrollbar-thumb")
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.click_and_hold(on_element=scrollbar).move_by_offset(0, 300)
        action.perform()
        time.sleep(2)

        try:
            add_business_view = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "add-business-view")
            break
        except:
            pass
```

Page loads dynamically, i belive that this is a reason for this error.
How shoud I scroll this page till the end? Or maybe there is a way to do it without scrolling?

Comment: What webdriver are you using? From SO, GH issues, and my own testing, geckodriver doesn't seem to work well with Selenium action_chains.

Answer (score 1):

against using a scrollbar, it is better to `execute_script` and a JS code to do it:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Replace with your preferred browser driver
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://yandex.kz/maps/")
time.sleep(3)

input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]/input[1]")
input_element.send_keys("Актау бар")
input_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)

while True:
    try:
        add_business_view = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "add-business-view")
        break
    except:
        # Scroll to the end of the page
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: it is not working. This code is performing without errors, but  it doesn`t scroll the page. As i Mentionrd before, I believe it is because the page is diveded into two frames. I need to scroll secondary frame but this code is scroling main frame. Unfortunatelly i did find how to switch between frames.

Answer (score 0):

$x("//ul[@class='search-list-view__list']/li[last()]")[0].scrollIntoView(false)

Let try with this code. I tried scroll to the element with scrollIntoView() function.
scrollIntoView(false) argument is meaning scroll to to element with this element in bottom of page.
scrollIntoView(true) is meaning scroll to element with this element in on top of page.

```
while True:
try:
    add_business_view = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "add-business-view")
    break
except:
    # Scroll to the last element which is displayed
    driver.execute_script("$x(\"//ul[@class='search-list-view__list']/li[last()]\")[0].scrollIntoView(false)")
    time.sleep(1)
```